# Error `Expected initialization of constant` when initializing a const vec2[] in the shader global scope

Tags: shader, godot, godot-shader-language

I have this defined outside of any functions in a shader.
I get the error `Expected initialization of constant`

```
const vec2 rels[4] = {
    vec2(-1.0, 0.0),
    vec2(1.0, 0.0),
    vec2(0.0, -1.0),
    vec2(0.0, 1.0)
};
```

But in the godot [documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/shading/shading_reference/shading_language.html#arrays) I can see it shows initializing an array of `vec2` in a function scope and a const array of scalars in the global scope.
Is it possible that initializing an array of `vec2` in the global scope is not supported?

Comment: After testing, it appears that const arrays are only supported inside function bodies, not in global scope. I think you can report this as a bug at https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues - Either this was an oversight on the implementation, or the documentation needs to address this. A bug either way.